Create new database without applying all migrations in EF Core
I have built a multi-tenant application that uses database per tenant strategy using EF Core. Over time, application has accumulated lots of migrations so when creating a brand new database, applying all migrations in order to get to the latest state takes a long time. Is there a way to create the "final" version of the database without applying all migrations and also reflect in _efmigrationhistory that all migrations have been applied so that future migrations can be applied correctly?

Assuming you don't have any changes that aren't in a migration, which I can't overstate... context.Database.EnsureCreated() will create tables based on your current model. Then you have to fake the history... You'll need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/services#using-services then IHistoryRepository can help you generate the sql script to create and insert each context.Database.GetMigrations() name. (then lots of testing...)

[Actually, I'm not certain if IHistoryRepository is a design time service. You might not need that bit.]
